# ASP.NET 5 Keeps crashing VS on project initialization

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bower

I have a solution with several MVC6 (asp.net 5) projects.
Each project uses bower and npm for packages. Bower has normalize-css and jquery installed.

9 out of 10 times I start the solution, it will crash during one of the mvc project's initialization-phase. If I debug I get the following error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'dependencies.jquery.pkgMeta.devDependencies', line 43, position 1.
```

If I remove jquery from bower dependencies and have only normalize-css left I get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'dependencies.normalize-css.pkgMeta._release', line 39, position 1.
```

I have uninstalled all bower packages and the problem is fixed, but I obviously still need the packages, so when adding jquery or another package again the crashing starts again.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

**edit for bower.json:**

```
  {
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "normalize-css": "3.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for fun, have you tried getting dependencies with Nuget or adding manually to rule out that it is bower?

Comment: If I remove them from bower and just manually reference them everything works ok.

Comment: Can you share the bower json file ?

Comment: @AmitPhilips added bower.json, which is virtually identical for all web projects.

Comment: Not sure what it could be, I am developing an ASP.NET Core app as well and dint face this issue.
Json.NET is being used to parse the bower.json file. Guessing that it is encountering a null instead of an object.
are you running the RC1 release with the latest updates ?

Comment: I have everything up to date. Ill keep trying stuff, thx for the suggestions.

Comment: just a suggestion, sometimes it pays of to manually check the project file if there is some character that has been misplaced.

Comment: I've had issues with the node_modules having too many nested directories before causing Visual Studio to crash. While not ideal, I've either made node_modules a hidden directory or removed it from the project so that Visual Studio didn't see it. This fixed those crashing issues. I'm not sure if this is the same issue, but maybe worth trying.

Comment: Ill give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like fixing another bug, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331585/2713516 worked wonders for the crashing.
It hasn't crashed since if I recall correctly. Either way, the combination of updating all dll's (especially newtonsoft.json, including removing old versions from disk) and going through the steps suggested by @LukaszDev has definitely made a big change.

Answer (score 1):

Try clean up nuget, npm and bower cache - it's help in my case:

Delete files in `your user folder`:

- `..\.dnx\packages\*` should be restored automatically, but please make backup first,
- `..\.nuget\packages\*` like above, please make backup first,
- `..\AppData\Local\bower\cache\*`
- `..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\*`
- `..\AppData\Local\Temp\*`

Of course close VS before doing this, and VS restore all packages on first running.

Also you can clean up `.vs` folder in your project folder - theoretically it's not related, but from my experience - it's helping with numbers VS issues.

Comment: I restarted VS about 8 times after trying your suggestions and it hasn't crashed once, so this might be the definitive solution, thanks :)

Comment: My joy was a bit premature, it just crashed 3 times in a row, maybe it will get less who knows.

Comment: Very strange... I work with VS2015 / MVC6 / Newtonsoft.JSON form 3 month and I have similar problem, but cleaning cache helps me definitely - after that I have no more problems... My last ideas: 1. Try reinstall all nugget packages (you can remove `project.lock.json` file) 2. Change `frameworks` to `dnx46` (I use this setting in my project) 3. Use different/latest version of nugget and bower packages (I use `Newtonsoft.Json v8.0.3` in my project) 4. Check your HDD maybe you have some kind of problem with disk that corrupting your files ?